# Cannot find package org.springframework.web.servlet

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

I am developing a Spring-MVC application and the package org.springframework.web.servlet seems to be missing (which is needed to use the DispatcherServlet). I included the following Maven dependencies:

```
   <!-- Spring framework --> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- JSTL --> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- for compile only, your container should have this -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Jackson JSON -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.6</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring Security module --> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Do I need to use other versions or am I missing a dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `spring-webmvc` dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```